# Как сделать данный код более простым и универсальным на JS?

Tags: javascript

Получаем такую строку ( string)

```
1.400.000 $
```

Задача, умножить данную строку на переменную rate и вернуть новое значения в таком состояние. ( Смена валюты) Я перевел из string в number( хотя мне кажется что не совсем корректно и можно рефакторинг сделать в данном случае )

Проблема еще в том как новое значения вернуть в состояние которая была, потому что новое значения получается слитно. Заранее спасибо ))

```
$('#cash-items li').on('click',function(){
    var name = $(this).text()
    var rate = $(this).data('rate')
    rate = parseFloat(rate)

    var itemsChanged = $('.rate_item__change')
    for(var i = 0; i<itemsChanged.length; i++){
      var price = $(itemsChanged[i]).text();
      price = price.replace(' $', '')
      price = price.replace('.', '')
      price = price.replace('.', '')
      price = parseFloat(price)

      var newPrice = price * rate;
      newPrice = parseInt(newPrice)
      $(itemsChanged[i]).text(newPrice + ' ' + name);
    }
})
```

Comment: Matcer задай формат. Или отформатируй с помощью регулярки

Comment: очевидно надо хранить просто число а при выводе форматировать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По всей видимости необходимо хранить просто число, и при выводе форматировать.

Присмотритесь к встроенным локале-специфичным форматтерам:

```js
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
});
console.log(formatter.format(1555.4)); /* $1,555.40 */


formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'RUB',
});
console.log(formatter.format(1555.4)); /* RUB 1,555.40 */


formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
});
console.log(formatter.format(1555.4)); /* 1 555,40 $ */


formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'RUB',
});
console.log(formatter.format(1555.4)); /* 1 555,40 ₽ */
```

Или используйте `Number.toLocaleString()`

```js
console.log((123567889.55)
       .toLocaleString('ru-RU')
       .split(/\s/).join('.'));
```

Comment: Не совсем. Вопрос даже легче, как номер 1400000 перевести в 1.400.000 ( да это станет строкой я в курсе )

Comment: @Danielqwaqwaqwa (123567889).toLocaleString() вроде этого?